# AngularJs - sharing data between routes issue

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-routing, ng-bind

I am working a tutorial on WEB DEVELOPMENT WITH_ANGULARJS AND BOOTSTRAP via "Packt".

At the moment i am trying to deploy the sharing of data (**JSON**)  between routes and here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e0Jwt9ArCsYIrQCnM9fp?p=preview) to check the implementation.

The issue that i came up with has to do with `data binding`, when i clicked on the "Report" link to change view i did got the view of the template but the data binding on it didn't worked.

Through developer tools it seems that `ng-binding` occurs but it posts that `No element selected.`

Is this an issue of AngularJs version compartibility or am i missing something else ?

Comment: That demo is using the same bad `href` you asked about several days ago. Demo works fine when you fix links and injections that don't exist

Comment: I updated the demo with the links corrected as advised but the binding still not working , which injections do not exist ?